# Is there any way Flyway Undo As per Installed rank instead of version?

Tags: flyway, undo

As per the current implementation flyway undo happens as per

1. Undo all migrations equal and above target version
2. In the reverse order of migration - (descending order of installed_rank).

Here I have the migration order as 3,1,2,4. When I am saying Undo -target 1, undo happens in the order 4,2,1,3.

My requirement here is when I say Undo -target 1, it should undo only 4,2,1, NOT 3.
Right now I have the option to do cheryyPick, which will help me to implement the above solution. But in my production environment, I may have around 200-300 scripts for a major release. So adding everything to cherryPick is going to be a tedious task for me.

Ideal solution for me to pick 'installed_rank' in place of 'version'. For e.g. in the above scenario, if I say Undo -target=2(installed_rank) then flyway is going to undo installed rank 4,3,2 - that's versions 4,2,1.

Can anyone help me implement the above solution?

Comment: When you say you have the migration order as 3,1,2,4, how are you specifying this order?

Comment: Sorry for the wrong question. I found that flyway is actually undoing the changes in the same way. But  there are some additional conditions because of which my scenario was failing.